# How to get the source of an image from upload form?

Tags: javascript, html, filereader

One of my first larger projects so please bear with me. I have a script which will help me resize an image and turn it into base64. This is how it begins:

```
var createImage = function (src) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    var img = new Image();

    img.onload = function() {
        deferred.resolve(img);
    };
    img.src = src;
    return deferred.promise();
};
```

And my question is to get the image source from the upload form to the script?

I've tried to stitch together (with help from other sources) a function with the Filereader API:

```
var createImageURL = function () {
    var fileinput = document.getElementById('fileinput');
    file = fileinput.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

    reader.onload = function (event) {
      var blob = new Blob([event.target.result]); 
      window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

      var blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    }
    return blobURL;
};
```

However this returns a GET error in the console.

Comment: `readAsArrayBuffer` is asynchrnous/non-blocking, `var blobURL` is in a different scope to your `return`, `return blobURL` will happen before file read finishes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than going via *Blob*, convert your `<input>`'s *File* to an *ObjectURL* directly, saving yourself a lot of trouble by keeping your code synchronous and requiring fewer lines of code.

```
function inputToURL(inputElement) {
    var file = inputElement.files[0];
    return window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
}

var url = inputToURL(document.getElementById('fileinput'));
createImage(url);
```

This works because a *File* is a *Blob* [per spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-file) (as pointed out by [Ray Nicholus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/486979/ray-nicholus))

---

It's not advised (as *File* inherits from *Blob* already) and highly unusual to want to convert between them, but not impossible. I'm including this so you can see how to structure *FileReader* code if you need it in future, not as a solution to your problem. To convert `<input type="file" />`'s first file to *Blob*, you would do

```
function fileToBlob(inputElement, callback) {
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function () {
        callback(new Blob([this.result]));
    }
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(inputElement.files[0]);
}
```

Where `callback` takes a *Blob* as it's first parameter. Remember that since the `readAsArrayBuffer` caused us to use a `callback`, we had to write this so it would work in an asynchronus environment.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected that was over-complicating things!

Comment: @SatoBolin I almost forgot that _File_ and _Blob_ work pretty much the same when I typed the answer originally, but the code I posted as written now works (I just tested it).

Comment: This is all completely unnecessary.  A File is already a Blob as well.  Simply call createObjectURL on the File object.  Have a look at [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-file).

Comment: Yes.  Using FileReader for this is not an acceptable solution.  I would suggest you adjust your code to contain only the correct solution (as I described in my comment) and explain why this one line solution is correct, instead of making adjustments to the roundabout and inneficient solution and then describing why this is not the best way to do this.

Comment: @PaulS. It works :) Maybe I'm silly to get emotional about these things but I've tried several scripts and this one is the first to work in Safari on iOS, so I'm really happy!

Comment: @RayNicholus swapped the top and bottom and put a line between them, made it stronger that you shouldn't go via _Blob_ and why I included the code. Does this fix the issues you have with it?

Comment: @SatoBolin the implementations of these interfaces are relatively new, so quite a few scripts out there at the moment use obsolete patterns or browser specific code, still.